# Execute liqubase migration for reduced time

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have a microservice which is using Liqubase to manage PosgtreSQL table data. Into the table I have ~300 000 rows of data from .sql script. Inserting this number of records will tale 3-4 hours. How I reduce the time for script execution?

Comment: Use `COPY` instead. Much faster than INSERT

Comment: 300000 records in 3 hours, that's 28 records per second. That is imho extremely slow, also for plain INSERT statements. Do you know what your performance bottleneck is? COPY is a very fast protocol, but on slow hardware it's still slow.

Comment: Yes, database server is in USA and I'm in Europe. Can you show me example please